# The roots of the equation $z^n=(1+z)^n$...

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex roots of the equation

> $$z^{n}=(1+z)^{n}$$

$A.$ are vertices of a regular polygon

$B.$ lie on a circle

$C.$ are collinear

$D.$ none of these

Don't know where to start.. Please help.!

NOTE:  $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498349/solving-an-exponential-equation-zn/498372#498372).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clearly, $z\ne0,$

So dividing either sides by $z^n,$ we have $$\left(1+\frac1z\right)^n=1$$

Using  [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications) & [Euler's formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula), $$1+\frac1z=e^{\frac{2m\pi i}n}=\cos\frac{2m\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2m\pi }n$$ where $m$ is any integer

$$\implies \frac1z=\cos\frac{2m\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2m\pi }n-1=i2\sin\frac{m\pi}n\cos\frac{m\pi}n-2\sin^2\frac{m\pi}n$$
$$=2i\sin \frac{m\pi}n\left(\cos\frac{m\pi}n+i\sin \frac{m\pi}n\right)$$ (using $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$)

$$z=\frac1{2i\sin \frac{m\pi}n\left(\cos\frac{m\pi}n+i\sin \frac{m\pi}n\right)}=\frac{{\cos\frac{m\pi}n-i\sin \frac{m\pi}n}}{2i\sin \frac{m\pi}n}=-\frac12-i\frac{\cot\frac{m\pi}n}2$$

Comment: Now what can we conclude from this ?

Comment: @Apurv, so if $z=x+iy,x=-\frac12.$ What can we conclude from here?

Comment: Ok.. So the points lie on x=-1/2. Hence the points are collinear. Thanks !!

Answer (score 8):

An easier method, stolen from comment to [an answer from a similar thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863085/70134).

If $z$ satisfies $z^n=(1+z)^n$, then $|z|^n=|1+z|^n$ and: $$|z|=|z+1|$$

The geometric interpretation is that the distance (in the complex plane) from $0$ to $z$ equals the distance from $-1$ to $z$. The locus of points with the same distance from $0$ and $-1$ is the vertical line: $$\mathrm{Re}\ z = -\frac12$$ so every solution to the original equation lies on this line.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite as $\left(\frac z{1+z}\right)^n = 1$.  Now from this you can work out the value of $\frac z{1+z}$, and note in particular that they lie on the unit circle.  And $\frac z{1+z}$ is a Möbius transform, so you should be able to figure out how its inverse maps the unit circle, remembering that Möbius transforms map circles and lines to circles and lines.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation).