# Is this question correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Suppose $A$ is a complex number and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^n = (A+1)^n= 1$, then the least value of $n$ is?

I really doubt this question is correct because if $A= A+1$ then $1=0$, which is obviously false. If it correct, I'd like to know the reason(s) and how do I *begin* solving the problem (full solution not needed).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643024/complex-numbers-exponential-numbers-proof

Comment: Such an $n\ge 1$ need not exists. Take $A=-1$.

Comment: $A^n=(A+1)^n \nRightarrow A=A+1$

Comment: Why @Wouter ? .

Comment: For the same reason that $a^2=b^2\nRightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^n=1$ and $(A+1)^n=1$ then both $A$ and $A+1$ lie on the unit circle.
Moreover $0$, $A$ and $A+1$ form the vertices of an equilateral triangle $T$.
The side of $T$ opposite $0$ is horizontal, so the only possible
$A$ are $A=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt 3)$ and $A=\frac12(-1-i\sqrt 3)$, as
$T$ must be invariant under reflection in the imaginary axis. Both
values of $A$ are primitive cube roots of unity and both
values of $A+1$ are primitive sixth roots of unity. Therefore
both $A^n=1$ and $(A+1)^n=1$ iff $n$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Why do both lie on the unit circle?

Comment: If $z^n=1$ then $|z|^n=1$ and so $|z|=1$. @Abcd

Comment: How can $|z|^n= 1$ imply $|z|=1$?