# $(z-1)^n+ (z+ 1)^n=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $z∈\mathbb{C}$ satisfy $(z-1)^n+ (z+ 1)^n=0$.

a, I have to show that $z = (1+w)/(1-w)$, where $w^n = -1$
b, Show that $w \bar w=1$
c, Deduce that $z$ lies on the imaginary axis.

I got the a part by rearranging for $z$, but I'm stuck for part b and c.

I know that $w \bar w=1$ means that $w=\cos(a) + i \sin(a)$, but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks for any helps or hints

Comment: What means (z 1)?

Comment: Could you answer to the previous question ? We think that it is $(z+1)$...

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607487/the-roots-of-the-equation-zn-1zn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with elementary arithmetic of complex numbers. You only need the multiplicativity of the complex absolute value and basic knowledge about complex conjugation, like $w\overline w = \lvert w \rvert^2$.

a) goes by algebra, as you already did.

b) From $w^n = -1$ you have $\lvert w \rvert^n = 1$, so $w\overline w = \lvert w \rvert^2 = 1^2 = 1$ (since $1$ is the only nonnegative real number $x$ with $x^n = 1$).

c) From $1 = w\overline w$, using a) and c),
$$\overline z = \frac{1 + \overline w}{1 - \overline w} = \frac{w\overline w + \overline w}{w\overline w - \overline w} = \frac{w + 1}{w - 1} = -z,$$
so $z$ must be imaginary.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^n&=-1\\\\
&=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}
\end{align}$$

for any integer $k$.

Then, we have

> $$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n} \tag 1$$

for $k=0,\dots, n-1$.

Solving $(1)$ for $z$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
z&=\frac{1+e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}}{1-e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}}\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{-i \cot\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)}
\end{align}$$

for $k=0,\dots, n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The part (c) can be deduced without calculating the solutions:
$$(z−1)^n + (z+1)^n = 0,$$
$$(z−1)^n = -(z+1)^n,$$
$$|z−1|^n = |z+1|^n,$$
$$|z−1| = |z+1|.$$
I.e., the solutions are equidistant of $1$ and $-1$, that is to say the are on the imaginary axis. Warning: *not all the points of the imaginary axis are solutions*,.