# Prove that all the roots of the equation $(1+z)^6+z^6=0$ are collinear.

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that all the roots of the equation $(1+z)^6+z^6=0$ are collinear.

---

$(1+z)^6+z^6=0$
$\frac{1+z}{z}=(-1)^{1/6}=e^{i\pi/6},e^{i3\pi/6},e^{i5\pi/6},e^{i7\pi/6},e^{i9\pi/6},e^{11i\pi/6}$,but i do not know how to solve further.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $z$ satisfies $(1+z)^6 + z^6 = 0$. Then we have $$|1+z|^6 = |z|^6 \implies |z| = |z+1|$$ It follows that $$z\overline{z} = |z|^2 = |z+1|^2 = (z+1)(\overline{z} + 1) = z\overline{z} + 2 \text{Re}(z) + 1 \implies \text{Re}(z) = \frac{-1}{2}$$ Thus, all roots of the equation $(1+z)^6 +  z^6$ lie on the line given by $\text{Re}(z) = -1/2$.

Comment: Ha!  Just beat me to it. :-) +1

Comment: Or, since $|z|=|z+1|$, $z$ is equidistant from $0$ and $-1$, so lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment from $0$ to $-1$.