# Find solution of equation $(z+1)^5=z^5$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I attempt to solve the equation

$(z+1)^5=z^5$.

My first approach is to expand the left hand side but ı get more complicated equation. So I couldn't go further. Secondly, I write equation as, since $z\neq0$,

$(\frac{z+1}{z})^5=1$, put $\xi=\frac{z+1}{z}$

and attempt to solve equivalent equation $\xi^5=1$. But this time it requires more computation to find solutions $z$. Can anyone suggest a simple way to solve this equation?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your second attempt looks like a good idea.

Comment: The second approach seems fine. You have $\xi = e^{2\pi i k / 5}$ for $k = 0,\dots,4$.

Comment: Note that you have an easy expression for $1+\frac{1}{z}$. Subtract $1$, take reciprocal.

Comment: It may be useful to think about what kind of mapping $\xi=1+z^{-1}$ is, since once you've solved in $\xi$ you have to deduce which $z$ would have produced these solutions.

Comment: @math: Here is a [similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498349/solving-an-exponential-equation-zn/498372#498372).

Answer (score 3):

$(z+1)^5=z^5$ implies that $|z+1|^2=|z|^2$, which implies that $x=\mathrm{Re}(z)=-\frac12$. Then $\left(\frac12+iy\right)^5=\left(-\frac12+iy\right)^5$ is a quadratic equation in $y^2$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve $\sqrt[n]{1}$:

- Draw the unit circle
- Draw the first solution, which is obviously $1+0i=\cos(0)+\sin(0)i$
- Repeat $n-1$ times: find the next solution by rotating the previous solution $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians

For example, $\sqrt[5]{1}$:

- $\cos(0)+\sin(0)i$
- $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})+\sin(\frac{2\pi}{5})i$
- $\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5})+\sin(\frac{4\pi}{5})i$
- $\cos(\frac{6\pi}{5})+\sin(\frac{6\pi}{5})i$
- $\cos(\frac{8\pi}{5})+\sin(\frac{8\pi}{5})i$

[image]

Comment: I suggest using radians as the argument of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Ritz: Yes, it has occurred to me while I was writing the answer. Will update; thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

To exploit symmetry, put $z=w-\frac 12$, which gives $z+1=w+\frac 12$.

Solving:

$$\begin{align}(z+1)^5&=z^5\\
\left(w+\frac 12\right)^5&=\left(w-\frac 12\right)^5\\
2\left[5w^4\left(\frac12\right)+10w^2\left(\frac 12\right)^3+\left(\frac 12\right)^5\right]&=0\\
80w^4+40w^2+1&=0\\
w^2&=\frac{-40\pm\sqrt{1600-320}}{160}\\
&=-\frac14 \left(1+\frac25\sqrt5\right)\\
w&=\pm\frac i2\sqrt{1+\frac25\sqrt5}\\
z&=-\frac12 \pm\frac i2\sqrt{1+\frac25\sqrt5}
\end{align}$$

---

Alternative method using comments on the OQ:

$$(z+1)^5=z^5\\
\left(\frac{z+1}z\right)^5=1\\
\left(1+\frac 1z\right)^5=1\\
1+\frac 1z=e^{i2n\pi/5}\\
z=\frac 1{e^{i2n\pi/5}-1}
$$

where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$.