# Solutions of $z^6 + 1 = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, quadratics

Solve:

$$z^6 + 1 = 0$$

That lie in the top region of the plane.

We know that:

$$(z^2 + 1)(z^4 - z^2 + 1) = 0$$

$$z = -i, i$$

We need to solve:

$$((z^2)^2 - (z)^2 + 1) = 0$$

$$z = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$$

But this is incorrect. How to do this then?

Comment: It's incorrect because in the last step, you forgot to write $z^2$.

Comment: There are already good answers to the question, but if you're interested in a general formula for equations of the form $z^n = a$ like yours $z^6=-1$, then it is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048779/compute-z3-26-18i/1048811#1048811) in another similar question I answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$z^6=-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies z=e^{\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi i}6}=\cos\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6+i\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6$$ where $0\le n\le 5$

Top region of the plane, $\implies$ the [ordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate) has to be $>0$

$\implies\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6>0\implies0<\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6<\pi\iff0<2n+1<6\implies-.5< n<2.5$

$\implies n=0,1,2$

Comment: This answer seems to miss the point of the question.

Comment: @quid, This pattern, will not allow the fuss due to solving in algebraic way

Comment: The point of the problem OP means to solve seems to be just dealing with this "fuss." In addition, what do you do if you want to know the algebraic form of the soltions, now? Say, you want to know the real part of the solutions?  Obviously you might reply that one knows the values of the triginometric functions there, but then one also knows the twelvth roots of unity at which point we might just say the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 6):

Only your last line is incorrect. What you should write is

$$z^2 = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of solving this equation is the method based on DeMoivre's Formula that Lab Bhattacharjee outlined.

That said, you can make your method work.  You found the roots $z \pm i$ by setting the factor $z^2 + 1$ equal to zero.  As Rasolnikov and 5xum noted, you should have obtained

$$z^2 = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$$

when you set the factor $z^4 - z^2 + 1$ equal to zero.

Let $z = a + bi$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then

\begin{align*}
z^2 & = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
(a + bi)^2 & = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
a^2 + 2abi - b^2 & = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}

Equating real and imaginary parts yields
\begin{align*}
a^2 - b^2 & = \frac{1}{2}\tag{1}\\
2ab & = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Solving equation 2 for $b$ yields
$$b = \frac{\pm\sqrt{3}}{4a}\tag{3}$$
Substituting this expression in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a^2 - \frac{3}{16a^2} & = \frac{1}{2}\\
16a^4 - 3 & = 8a^2\\
16a^4 - 8a^2 & = 3\\
16a^4 - 8a^2 + 1 & = 4 && \text{complete the square}\\
(4a^2 - 1)^2 & = 4\\
4a^2 - 1 & = \pm 2\\
4a^2 & = 3 && \text{since $a \in \mathbb{R}$}\\
a^2 & = \frac{3}{4}\\
a & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}
Substituting this expression into equation 3 yields the four roots 
$$z = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}i$$
of the equation $z^4 - z^2 + 1 = 0$. As you can check, these roots correspond to the values $n = 0, 2, 3, 5$ in the formula Lab provided.

Comment: "The simplest way"...then let us start from scratch and see who has finished first with an explanation. Obvioulsy if you are willing to assume all kinds of things the problem is "simple." Upvoted though for giving the details to the question actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve $\sqrt[2n]{-1}$:

- Draw the unit circle
- Draw the first solution, which is obviously $0+1i=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})i$
- Repeat $2n-1$ times: find the next solution by rotating the previous solution $\frac{\pi}{n}$ radians

For example, $\sqrt[6]{-1}$:

- $\cos(\frac{ 3\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{ 3\pi}{6})i$
- $\cos(\frac{ 5\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{ 5\pi}{6})i$
- $\cos(\frac{ 7\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{ 7\pi}{6})i$
- $\cos(\frac{ 9\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{ 9\pi}{6})i$
- $\cos(\frac{11\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{11\pi}{6})i$
- $\cos(\frac{13\pi}{6})+\sin(\frac{13\pi}{6})i$

[image]

Comment: Your diagram shows the root $$\cos\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{3}\right) + \sin\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{3}\right)i$$ but you omitted it from your explanation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yep, one root was missing. Now fixed, thanks :)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: The $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ thing was by itself wrong. I've fixed that as well...

Comment: True.  The root I was looking at was actually $$\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)i$$  My apologies.

Comment: I edited your third line to change degrees to radians since you were working in radians.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have previously answered a [similar question on $\sqrt[5]{1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928735/find-solution-of-equation-z15-z5/928762#928762), where I answered in degrees. Someone has later suggested to change the $180$ to $\pi$, and so I did that, but left the "degrees". Thank you for the correction, I will apply it there too. BTW, which one do you think is easier to understand, radians or degrees?